# what does %*%+ mean in matrix operations?

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I read a piece of code somewhere where the following operation is performed between matrices x and y

```
x %*% + y
```

I know that `%*%` means matrix multiplication but what does `%*% +` mean? I tried it out in R and I get the same results for both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [precedence of operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), unary minus and plus (`+`, `-`) are evaluated before `%any%` (including `%*%`). Therefore, `x %*% + y` is the same as `x %*% (+y)` (which is equal to `x %*% y`).

Comment: thanks! that's very clear! Do you know under what circumstances would someone use `x %*% + y` rather than just `x %*% y` if they are the same?

Comment: @Amazonian, AFAIK, there is no circumstance that the `+` is necessary. But I guess someone might write this along with `x %*% (-y)` and want to hightlight the signs.